# WinDbg Extension C++ dprintf Doesn't Display Until Function Exits

Tags: c++, windbg

When used within a WinDbg extension is there a way to ensure dprintf updates the WinDbg console output immediately, instead of waiting until the end of the function?

This doesn't seem to be covered in the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542750(v=vs.85).aspx)

Example code

```
DECLARE_API(myextension)
{
    dprintf("Print some text\r\n");
    Sleep(5000);
}
```

If in WinDbg I load this extension and execute it

```
!myextension
```

There is a 5 second delay before the text is printed to the console - how can I ensure this text displays immediately.

In the actual solution I have a long running task and want output to continue while the task runs; however I can reproduce the issue by using a sleep as well.

Comment: Is it possible that your extension runs on the UI thread and WinDbg can simply not update yet? What happens if you insert a `DoEvents()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wdbgexts style extensions are old and have some limitations
you should try writing engextcpp style extensions
or atleast dbgeng style extensions

here is a dbgeng style sample

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbgeng.h>
PDEBUG_CLIENT2   g_Client = NULL;
PDEBUG_CONTROL2  g_Control = NULL;
HRESULT CALLBACK  DebugExtensionInitialize(PULONG Version, PULONG Flags)
{
  *Version = DEBUG_EXTENSION_VERSION(1, 0);
  *Flags = 0;
  DebugCreate(__uuidof(IDebugClient2),(void **)&g_Client);  
  return g_Client->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugControl2),(void **)&g_Control);  
}
HRESULT CALLBACK testsleep(PDEBUG_CLIENT , PCSTR )
{
  ULONG now = 0;
  g_Control->GetCurrentSystemUpTime(&now);
  g_Control->Output(DEBUG_OUTPUT_NORMAL,"sleep %x or %d now at %d\n",5000,5000,now);
  Sleep(5000);
  g_Control->GetCurrentSystemUpTime(&now);
  g_Control->Output(DEBUG_OUTPUT_NORMAL,"woke  %x or %d now at %d\n",5000,5000,now);
  return S_OK;
}
```

result of running !testsleep in windbg

```
0:000> .time
....
System Uptime: 0 days 12:50:30.766
.....
0:000> !testsleep
sleep 1388 or 5000 now at 46235
woke  1388 or 5000 now at 46240
0:000> .formats 0n12*0n3600+0n50*0n60+0n30
.....
  Decimal: 46230
```

sample for engextcpp style extension neat an clean dont even have to include windows.h

```
#include <engextcpp.hpp>
class EXT_CLASS : public ExtExtension {
public:
    EXT_COMMAND_METHOD(testsleep);
};
EXT_DECLARE_GLOBALS();
EXT_COMMAND(testsleep,"","")
{
  ULONG now =0;
  m_Control2->GetCurrentSystemUpTime(&now);
  Out("Sleeping for 5000 milliseconds from %d\n",now);
  Sleep(5000);
  m_Control2->GetCurrentSystemUpTime(&now);
  Out("Slept    for 5000 milliseconds upto %d\n",now);  
}
```

a run from !testSleep

```
0:000> !testsleep
Sleeping for 5000 milliseconds from 48921
Slept    for 5000 milliseconds upto 48926
```

Comment: Thanks, using Output worked. In my existing extension I was able to use Output method on the IDebugControl4 interface ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550526(v=vs.85).aspx ) Works perfectly. I will investigate using the engextcpp style extension as well.

Comment: i added an engextcpp style sample code also take a look

Comment: you can FlushCallbacks to ensure the outputcallback buffer is flushed to windbg screen (output call backs are buffered internally and lazy flushed in regular course)